# Qual a diferença entre Media Rule e Media Query?

Tags: css, css3

Às vezes vejo um desses dois termos sendo mencionados quando o assunto é responsividade ou ajuste do conteúdo a variações de tipos de telas e de dispositivos.

Olhando [esta documentação no W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) é dito que:

> Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3. (traduzindo: *Media query é uma técnica CSS apresentada no CSS3*).

E o *Media Rule*, onde entra nisso? Reforçando a pergunta: ambos os termos representam a mesma coisa? Se não, qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Media Rule` que você diz são as `@media` que são regras. Elas são usadas para aplicar um estilo com base no resultado de uma ou mais `Media Query`. Ou seja, o estilo que está contido na regra @media será aplicado quando a condição (`Media Query`) for verdadeira.